# Getting the dimensions of a rotated image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas which I draw an image onto. The image can be rotated to a certain amount of degrees before being drawn (EG: 30).

I need to draw a box to contain the drawn image; this would be easy but the width and height change depending on the angle the image is rotated to.

I have seen some very similar questions here, but I couldn't implement the answers into my code because they are either written in another language like ActionScript or they are rotating a div or other element not within a canvas. I haven't been able to work out the main math behind it.

I have created a JSFiddle for you to adapt:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZY7Ux/

I have created two functions in this JSFiddle:

```
drawImageToCanvasRotated(URL, X, Y, Angle);
drawRectangle(X, Y, Width, Height);
```

You should note that the position values are for the center of the image / rectangle.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this pure geometry? Wouldn't the size of the bounding rectangle be [width*(sin(x)+cos(x)), height*(sin(x)+cos(x))]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rotate the image, so the new width becomes a combination of:

- the x dimension of the width, which gets a little smaller than the full width (using the cosine)
- the x dimension of the height, which gets a little higher than 0 (using the sine)

An analogous calculation applies for the new height. http://jsfiddle.net/ZY7Ux/1/

```
var a = Width * Math.cos(Angle);
var b = Height * Math.sin(Angle);
var c = a + b;

var p = Width * Math.sin(Angle);
var q = Height * Math.cos(Angle);
var r = p + q;

context.strokeRect(
    X - c / 2,
    Y - r / 2,
    c,
    r
);
```

Comment: @CHRIS: Note that this calculation fails with negative angles / angles greater than 90 degrees, because the idea behind it doesn't apply in that case.

Comment: I'm having difficulty adapting this to work with all values between -360 to 360. I've tried doing a primive if(imageRotation >= 90)... else... but I think that it can be done better. Please help, thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand how: context[i ? "lineTo" : "moveTo"](xM[i], yM[i]); works. What are the variables which store the rectangle's starting X and Y and ending X and Y or width and height? I've tried logging all the values of xM and yM and changing the line drawing code to: context.strokeStyle = "#00F"; context.strokeRect(X + xM[0], Y + yM[0], X + xM[1], Y + yM[1]); but as I say, I'm not sure what exactly the xM and yM variables store.

Comment: @CHRIS: Each pair `xM[i], yM[i]` is a corner of the bounding rectangle. It is composed using the minimal/maximal x/y of the rotated rectangle.

Comment: image in examples doesnt exist any longer :(